# Transform one JSON array in two jquery arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I'm trying to collect information from a JSON file in my jQuery script.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "settings.json",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    error: function(){
        $('.slideMe').css("display", "none");
    },
    success: function(getSettings){
        // My code..
    }
});
```

Here's my JSON:

```
{
    "slider": {
        "Nb": "6",
        "Height": "390px",
        "Width": "full",
        "FadeInit": "1000",
        "ChangeTime": "10000",
        "FadeInTime": "550",
        "FadeOutTime": "850"
    },
    "thumb": {
        "Mode": "preview",
        "Background": "#00000",
        "Color": "grey",
        "Height": "70",
        "Width": "152",
        "Opacity": "0.4",
        "FadeTime": "50"
    }
}
```

I want to use values like this:

```
alert(slider.FadeInit);
```

But with my code I have to write:

```
alert(getSettings.slider.FadeInit);
```

I tried a lot of solutions ( $.each() .. $.makeArray() .. etc..) without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want. This is as "automatic"  as it gets.  I have read that is not a good option to use the `eval()` function, but I don't know why. Maybe someone could comment this answer explaining the reason.

```
 $.each(getSettings, function(key, value) {
       str = key+' = '+'getSettings.'+key;
       eval(str);
 });

 alert(slider.FadeInit);
```

I'm not sure this is the only way to do it,  but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the JSON object you can simply declare:

```
 var slider = getSettings.slider
 var thumb = getSettings.thumb
```

And use the values as you wanted to.

Comment: I thought this solution but in the future I'll had more JSON Objects (slider, thumb, object3, object4, etc..) and with this solution I will have to declare each time I add and object.. I'm looking for an "automatic" solution.
But your answer is a good solution. Thank you !

Comment: what u mean with the "automatic" solution"

Comment: If I add some more objects in my Json, I don't want to have to declare each time in my jquery code.
If I have an object "slider", an object "thumb", and an object "settings" .. I want to use for example `thumb.x` or `settings.y` without declare `var thumb = getSettings.thumb` and `var settings = getSettings.settings`

Comment: The other answer I posted does that.